# Porque este NumberFormat funciona diferente en distintos celulares

Tags: android

la question es que trato de mostrar un numero con milesimas y eso, el problema es que me funciona nada mas en unos cuantos celulares, es decir
por ejemplo donde dice `preciou` tiene que ir algo como 2.94 y al operarlo multiplicando por `cantidad` (por 100 por ejemplo) en algunos celulares sale 294, pero en otros sale 29.400

```
final String separador = "###.###.###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(separador);
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getInstance();

int cantidad;
float  preciou; int sumatotal=0;
cantidad=Integer.parseInt(cantidad_producto.getText().toString());
//preciou=Integer.parseInt(precio.getText().toString());
preciou=  nf.parse(precio.getText().toString()).floatValue();                    sumatotal= (int) (cantidad*preciou);

preciototal.setText(decimalFormat.format(sumatotal));
temp.setText(String.valueOf(sumatotal));
```

**EDITADO**
Olvidenlo, lo "Arregle" el tema era el idioma del celular, en los celulares que funcionaba estaba en Español(Estados Unidos) y los que no, en Español(Latam)
Ahora... Una forma que funcione en un solo idioma? o que funcione sin importar el idioma?

Comment: Por favor, por la solución como respuesta y luego la aceptas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funciona diferente por la configuración del idioma en el celular.

Por ejemplo teniendo el valor 2940000 , este se puede mostrar diferente usando el formato "`###,###,###`":

- Inglés: `2,940,000`
- Francés: `2 940 000`
- Coreano: `2,940,000`
- Alemán: `2.940.000`

en este caso para que no importando la configuración del lenguaje no cambie el formato, debes definir un `Locale` para tener un mismo formato, por ejemplo `Locale.ENGLISH`:

```
final String separador = "###,###,###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(separador, DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

o puedes definirlo de esta forma usando un `Locale` definiendo el idioma español, ejemplo

```
Locale specialLocale  = new Locale("es", "ES");
String formatPattern = "###,###,###";

DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(specialLocale);
decimalFormat.applyPattern(formatPattern);
```